# Animate image to a div vue.js

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, css-animations

Is there any way to animate an image to a certain div with vue.js animations?

I basically want to implement an "Add to cart" animation where the moment the visitor clicks on "Add to cart", the product's image moves to the shopping cart icon and then disappears. While the image is moving, its size should be getting smaller and smaller.

Can this be done with vue animations?

Answer (score 1):

## tl; dr;

#### yes

---

The way I'd go about it is using the `transform` css property and animate the `translate` and `scale` parameters; and to calculate the locations, I would use vue's `$ref` and/or `$el` instance properties.